# SCCM Powershell not logging to Network Drive

Tags: powershell, logging, sccm

I have written a PowerShell script to be deployed via SCCM.

The scripts runs fine locally but not when deployed via SCCM.

I have launched a PowerShell script as System account however I cannot change to a network share for example `\\server\logs.$\`but when I change it to `C:\temp` it works.

Setup share has all the correct permissions and is being ran locally using the System account.

Does anyone have any ideas on to solve this.

Comment: Has the site server computer account got access to the share and folder? I'd also remove the dot from the sharename so \\server\logs.$ becomes \\server\logs$

Comment: I cannot tell if the file path is blocking the script from running or it is the execution policy.

Comment: You might be giving share permissions to the LocalSystem account of the local machine. Try giving access to the remote computer account? Like in the answer here - [grant access to network resources](http://serverfault.com/questions/135867/how-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account/135874#135874)